# Factory reset of iPod classic without iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipod, reset

Is there a way to perform a factory reset of an iPod Classic without having to use iTunes?

This may seem like an obscure question, but I am suffering from the following:  I tried some 3rd party iPod management tool, performed a db rebuild with it, and now my iPod does not appear in iTunes or any other software.  Windows 7 recognises it as an iPod, and the disk partition on it is accessible.

iTunes does not detect it.  I have nothing to lose, so I don't mind doing a full reset/format etc.

I am running a Windows 7 machine (32 bit).

**EDIT:**  I solved the problem by upgrading to iTunes 10.  I was running an old version (I think 8 or 9).  There could have possibly been a compatibility problem with Windows 7 and the older versions?

Comment: Have you tried holding down the Menu and centre button at the same time for a few seconds? This used to work to tell it to turn off, and then iTunes would take over from there. Make sure the device service is running, as Brandon suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that the Apple Mobile Device service is running, I've had this problem before by taking it out of startup. 
EDIT: If you don't know how to find it, go to Start>type "Services.msc" and it should be one of the first items in the list. Right click and click "Start" if it's not started.

Comment: Thanks, the service was running though - so that wasn't the problem.  See my edit above for what I did to solve the problem.  Im going to award you with the chosen answer as it is good advice when diagnosing this problem.

Comment: Ahh, that was something I overlooked. I'm new to the community, so I'm still trying to find the right things to offer.